# Polymorphic call into an overridden method is failing. Instead the base class's virtual method is being called

Tags: c#

In my project, I have an `Item` class. It has this virtual method called `Use()`

```
    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Item(string name, int maxAllowedStackCount = DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE)
    {
        Name = name;
        MaxAllowedStackCount = maxAllowedStackCount;
    }

    public virtual void Use(UseData useData)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{Name} has been used");
        _useCallback?.Invoke();
    }
```

`Item` serves as a base class for other classes. For example, I have a `MeleeItem` that inherits from it. MeleeItem also overrides the `Use()` method. Here's the Use() code from MeleeItem (and the constructor)

```
    public MeleeItem()
    {
        MaxAllowedStackCount = WEAPON_MAX_STACK; //this is just an int
    }

    public override void Use(UseData useData)
    {
        if (Durability <= 0)
            return;

        PlayUseAnimation(useData.ItemUser.GetAnimator());
        var target = GetTarget(useData.ItemUser);
        GameManager.Instance.StartCoroutine(DoDamage(useData.ItemUser, target));

        base.Use(useData);
    }
```

Lastly, I have a class called `ItemStack`. ItemStack is a wrapper for Items, where it keeps track of their count. It does other things too, but that's not relevant. ItemStack has this field (constructor also included):

```
    public Item Item;

    public ItemStack(Inventory inventory, Item item)
    {
        Item = item;
        Inventory = inventory;
    }
```

So, here is my problem. When I call `itemStack.Item.Use()`, polymorphism isn't working. Instead of calling the subclass's Use(), it's calling the base class's Use().

Here is my test:

```
    [Test]
    public void UseItem_WeaponLosesDurabilityWithEachUse()
    {
        var inv = new Inventory(10);

        // we create a new MeleeItem. MeleeItem inherits from DurabilityItem, which inherits from Item
        var axe = new MeleeItem {Name = "Axe"};
        axe.Durability = 10;

        // ItemStack is a wrapper for Items
        var stack = new ItemStack(inv, axe, 1);
        var useData = new UseData();

        // Polymorphism is failing here. It is NOT calling Use() of MeleeItem. Instead it's calling
        // the Use() of Item. I've tried stepping into the Use() method, and it goes straight to 
        // the Use() method of item.
        stack.Item.Use(useData);
        Assert.AreEqual(axe.Durability, 10 - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It seems unlikely that this is an issue in the CLR, but without being able to reproduce the issue, it'll be hard to tell where the problem is. (You haven't shown your `ItemStack` constructor, for example... if that tries to clone the item, maybe that's the problem...)

Comment: please provide the entire code to answer your question ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added the constructors for all the classes I've mentioned

Comment: I tried to put together a repro based on the information you gave (https://dotnetfiddle.net/dq7Fxv) but can't reproduce your problem. Please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] which someone can run, like the one I put together on dotnetfiddle

Comment: Your MeleeItem isn't inheriting anything..?

Comment: Remove "override" keyword in your inherited class and see what compiler says. If it does not complain then you may have missed something.

Comment: I was putting together an dotnetfiddle example with all my code, and I found the problem. The DurabilityItem class, which I didn't even think was important enough to show in my example, had `public virtual void Use(UseData useData)` instead of `public override void Use(UseData useData)`. I can't believe it was such a stupid mistake, sorry everyone.

Comment: @Andrio i just check your code and it's works fine , when beaucause `stack.Item.Use(useData)`  it's call the Use method of your subclass .

Comment: @Andrio: This is why it's always worth putting together the repro as part of preparing a question. Very often you'll find the problem while you do so, and even if you don't we'll be in a much better position to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll do that in the future, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the DurabilityItem class (which I didn't even think was important enough to add to my original post), I had this:

```
    public virtual void Use(UseData useData)
    {
        if (Durability > 0)
        {
            base.Use(useData);
            Durability--;
        }
    }
```

But I should have had this:

```
    public override void Use(UseData useData)
    {
        if (Durability > 0)
        {
            base.Use(useData);
            Durability--;
        }
    }
```

I had marked it as virtual when it should have been marked as override.

Comment: There was not even a single case of inheritance in your shown code. We have no idea if you were even doing any explicit inheritance.

Comment: Note that you should have got a compiler warning from this. Its always worth fixing your warnings!